# Any ways to accelerate the for loop in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, time-series

Actually, I'm dealing with time series data one batch at a time in a for loop. Within the batch, there are 14,400 rows, I need to check if there is any vacation of the time series and make it up if necessary. I wonder if there are some more efficient ways to scan rows and do specific operations, namely ways to accelerate the for loop in Python. By the way, I'm using Pandas, maybe there are better libraries I can use?

```
for start_row in range(0, total_rows, batch_size):
    end_row = min(start_row + batch_size, total_rows)
    temp_df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx',
                            skiprows=range(1, start_row), nrows=batch_size)
    count = count + 1
    for row in range(1, len(temp_df)):

        
        current_value = temp_df.iloc[row, 0]
        previous_value = temp_df.iloc[row - 1, 0]
        if temp_df.isna().iloc[row, 0]:
            break;

        time_difference = pd.Timestamp(current_value) - pd.Timestamp(previous_value)
        desired_interval = pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
        temp_df.loc[row, 'NotEqual'] = (current_value != previous_value)
        temp_df.loc[row, 'IntervalEqual'] = (time_difference == desired_interval)

        if temp_df.loc[row, 'NotEqual'] == False:
            print(count, row)
            temp_df = temp_df.drop(temp_df.index[row], axis=0)

        if temp_df.loc[row, 'IntervalEqual'] == False:
            print(count, row)
            print(time_difference)
            insert_index = row
            new_timestamps = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp(previous_value)+desired_interval,
                                           end=pd.Timestamp(current_value)-desired_interval,
                                           freq=desired_interval)
            new_rows = [{'时间': ts.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'Column1': 9999, 
                         'Column2': 9999} for ts in new_timestamps]
            temp_df1 = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)

            df_before = temp_df.iloc[:insert_index]
            df_after = temp_df.iloc[insert_index:]
            temp_df = pd.concat([df_before, temp_df1, df_after], ignore_index=True)
            print('Insetred:')
            print(temp_df)
            temp_df = temp_df.drop(temp_df.columns[-1], axis=1)
            temp_df = temp_df.drop(temp_df.columns[-1], axis=1)

        if temp_df.loc[row, 'Column1'] < 0:
            temp_df.loc[row, 'Column1'] = 9999

        if temp_df.isna().loc[row, 'Column2']:
            if temp_df.loc[row-1,'Column2']==temp_df.loc[row+1,'Column2']:
                temp_df.loc[row,'Column2']=temp_df.loc[row+1,'Column2']

            else:
                temp_df.loc[row,'Column2']=(temp_df.loc[row-1,'Column2']+temp_df.loc[row+1, 'Column2'])/2

    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df])
```

The above is my code and I'd appreciate much if you could offer suggestions! And this is my first time to ask a question on StackOverflow and I'm not sure whether my question and code is in a right and appropriate format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't know if you implemented these points but look:

**Reading Files**:

- Read the Excel file just once if possible.
- If your data is too big for memory, consider using formats like Parquet or HDF5 which read data faster.

**Use Pandas Efficiently**:

- Instead of going row by row, use Pandas' built-in functions which work on the whole column at once. They're faster!
- Convert your time data to Pandas' datetime format for easy time calculations.

**Changing DataFrames**:

- It's slow to change DataFrames inside a loop. Instead, gather what you want to add, and do it all at once after the loop.

**Choose the Right Tool**:

- Think about using libraries like `NumPy` for heavy calculations.
  `Dask` is another option that can help when working with very large data.

**Use All Your Computer's Power**:

- If you have a powerful computer with multiple processing cores, split the work across them for faster results. You can do this with Python’s `multiprocessing` or libraries like `joblib`.

Here's a refined code for you:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx')

data["时间"] = pd.to_datetime(data["时间"])

# Helper function to fill missing data
def fill_missing_rows(group):
    res = []
    desired_interval = pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
    
    for i in range(1, len(group)):
        current_time = group.iloc[i]
        prev_time = group.iloc[i-1]
        
        time_difference = current_time - prev_time
        
        if time_difference > desired_interval:
            num_intervals = time_difference // desired_interval - 1
            for j in range(num_intervals):
                new_time = prev_time + (j + 1) * desired_interval
                res.append({'时间': new_time, 'Column1': 9999, 'Column2': 9999})
                
    return pd.DataFrame(res)

missing_rows = data.groupby(np.arange(len(data)) // batch_size)["时间"].apply(fill_missing_rows).reset_index(drop=True)


final_data = pd.concat([data, missing_rows], ignore_index=True).sort_values("时间")

# Use vectorized operations wherever possible to increase performance
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh! These are quite useful suggestions for me, and I should have considered more. I will try it later. Anyway, thank you so much!